# Cant mail a couple of variables and strings

Tags: php, string, email, variables

So I am developing a script that will eventually be run as a shell to detect ip address changes by comparing the current ip (

```
//get_ip.php
<?php
$current_ip = file_get_contents('http://www.ipaddresscheck.comlu.com/ip.php');
?>
```

)

(if anyone is interested, http://www.ipaddresscheck.comlu.com/ip.php  will return ONLY the public IP of your machine/ router)

to the latest one recorded in mysql.  Right now, I can't even email out a fake old IP and a real current ip. When i try to email the old and new IPs, it will only work I i put the old ip variable in the spot for the current or nothing at all.  it should say

```
The old IP adresss was --- ".$old_ip."
The new IP address is  --- ".$current_ip."
```

but that won't work.  the only thing that works is

```
The old IP adresss was --- ".$old_ip."
The new IP address is  --- ".$old_ip."
```

or

```
The old IP adresss was --- ".$old_ip."
The new IP address is  --- 


<?php
//Get IP
include 'get_ip.php';
//Connect to SQL
mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
//Select database
mysql_select_db("ip_changes") or die(mysql_error());
//Get Date Info
$date = date("D M Y");
$time = date("H i s");
//Generate SQL query
$sql="INSERT INTO ip (date, time, current_ip)
VALUES ('$date', '$time', '$current_ip')";
//Execute SQL
mysql_query($sql);
//$sqlcurrent = mysql_query(SELECT current_ip FROM ip ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);
echo $current_ip;
$new_ip = $current_ip;
//Send Mail
$old_ip = '192.168.0.1';
$to = "justinmarmorato@gmail.com";
$subject = "IP Address Change";
$message = "Hello! This is an automated message from the IPMS.  An IP address chamge has been 
detected.
//Right here, I can only send out $old_ip, and nothing else.  The date and time at the bottom does work.
The old IP adresss was --- ".$old_ip."
The new IP address is  --- ".$old_ip."
The IP address change was detected at ---". $date. ' , '. $time;
$message1 = 'Old IP:'.$old_ip.
'New IP:'.$current_ip;
$from = "no-reply@http://mar-remote-net.dns2.us";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo 'Old IP:'.$old_ip.
'New IP:'.$current_ip;
?>
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Can you check that your code for getting IP is working correctly, ie in get_ip.php file

Comment: just echo the message before sending it to mail what it contains.

Answer (score 0):

No doubt, that it doesn't work, because you are using a wrong variable name:

```
$message = "Hello! ...";
//why is it called message1?
$message1 = 'Old IP:'.$old_ip. 'New IP:'.$current_ip;

//here you are sending $message
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: earlier, i tried to make each message line  variable and add them together. it looked like $message1, $message2 $message3...  but basically, bow I've tried getting the ip (getting the source of that page) on the mail script, eliminating get_ip.php, but i still can't get anything to work...

Comment: @JustinMarmorato Put var_dump($message);var_dump($message1);exit; before $from = "no-reply@http://mar-remote-net.dns2.us"; and let me know, what it prints.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...

```
$finalmessage = <<< EOT
    Hello! This is an automated message from the IPMS. An IP address change has been detected.
    <html>
    <style>
    table, th, td
    {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-color:grey;
    }
        </style>
    <table class='table'>
    <tr>
    <td>Old IP</td><td>New IP</td><td>Time Detected</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>$old_ip</td><td>$new_ip</td><td>$date  $time</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </html>
EOT;
```